# Axios POST resolves to undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I started switching my project from standard Fetch API to Axios library. Axios seemed great, with all the interceptors, custom instances, etc. The problem started with POST requests.

I have an custom axios instance defined as:

```js
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  timeout: 10000
});
```

Im using it for most of my API calls and most of them are fine, except one that I got stuck on for a incredibly frustrating amount of time.
Using POST request, it seems that the Promise is resolved into `undefined`.
Lets take a look at a code:

```js
export async function saveIncomes(incomes) {
  const { added, changed } = incomes;
  const add_res = axiosInstance.post(`${INCOMES_URL}`, added).then(console.log);
  const change_responses = [];
  for (let changed_row of changed) {
    change_responses.push(
      axiosInstance.put(`${INCOMES_URL}${changed_row.id}/`, changed_row)
    );
  }
  let finalRes = [];
  try {
    finalRes = await axios.all([add_res, ...change_responses]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  return finalRes;
}
```

This function takes two arrays of incomes - added and changed (since two http methods),
prepare all promises for them (I have bulk POST but not PUT on my API) and call `axios.all` to run them concurrently. Now, the fun begins.
When I post the correct data that is validated by API and returns 201 created, all is fine, the Promise resolves to current axios Response object, but when the data is incorrect and status is 400, it resolves to undefined.
Example:

```js
axios.all([p1, p2, p3]) // correct data
 -> [<response1>, <response2>, <response3>

axios.all([p1, p2, p3]) // incorrect data
 -> [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

It doesnt throw an error, it resolves, but to no avail.
The browser however gets the data correctly (I mean, its status 400, but there IS an response body).

I have no clue what to do anymore, I'm new to axios but it looked less problematic then it is now.

My frontend app is on React.js, some parts of it still uses fetch API, because its a work in progress.
Backend is in python Django with DRF.

EDIT:
Also, I'm using interceptors heres the code:

```js
export function setResponseInterceptor({ onSuccess, onError }) {
  if (!onSuccess) {
    onSuccess = response => response;
  }
  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    if (isHandlerEnabled(response.config)) {
      response = onSuccess(response);
    }
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }, onError);
}

export function setRequestInterceptor({ beforeSend, onError }) {
  if (!beforeSend) {
    beforeSend = cfg => cfg;
  }
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(cfg => {
    if (isHandlerEnabled(cfg)) {
      cfg = beforeSend(cfg);
    }
    return cfg;
  }, onError);
}
```

Comment: Just for sure: I don't see definition of `changed_row`

Comment: @Jax-p its just an object to be send as JSON to the API. If you need an actual information about the fields please tell me, but I dont see it relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Axios** [call](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/axios.js#L46) `Promise.all()` on `axios.all()`, which run promises asynchroniously. Looking at [MDN definition of promises .all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) reject you can see the following :

> #### Using Promise.all
>
> Promise.all waits for all fulfillments (or the first rejection).
>
> #### Rejection
>
> If any of the passed-in promises reject, Promise.all asynchronously rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, whether or not the other promises have resolved.

As your API return 401, it return the rejection of the failling promise, ignoring the others.

## Catch a rejection

Using `.catch`, you will receive a unique promise rejection as argument and should be able to read it's value.

```
// Using .catch:
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5])
.then(values => { 
  console.log(values);
})
.catch(error => { 
  console.error(error.message)
});
```

Looking at your code, you need to make sure your function `saveIncomes` handle properly this behaviour.

Comment: Doesn't my try/catch block should catch rejected `axios.all` since its async/await syntax? If it does, it still not triggers the block in catch (`console.log`), so I thought that the promises are not rejected, but fulfilled.

Comment: Try will succeed as no error is thrown and `finalRes` is a `Promise.reject()` object. And if it does, you need to call `throw new Error('blablabla');` to notify the failure to `saveIncomes()`

Comment: Thanks, I will dig into that, you explanation cleared the this up for me, It looks like I got confused with the whole fulfilled/rejected concepts. Much appreciated!